# Why is the manual of apt incomplete?

Tags: command-line, apt, documentation

I would like to see what are the command-line switches of `apt list` but after 30min of research I don't manage to find a lot of information about it...

I tried to type `apt list --help`, `man apt` and `man apt-get` but didn't get much information especially about what I search. I would even say the documentation of `apt` is very short for a program this important on Linux.

Anyone knows where I can get more information about `apt` commands ?

I'm pretty sure there is a command which is something like this : `apt list --installed`. But I don't even manage to find it in the documentation... It's very puzzling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Man apt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/apt.8.html):

> ```
> list
>        list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can display a list of
>        packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports glob(7) patterns for matching
>        package names as well as options to list installed (--installed), upgradeable
>        (--upgradeable) or all available (--all-versions) versions.
> ```

Seems to cover the basics.

Comment: My bad ! ^^' I guess the fact that nothing was displayed when I typed `apt list --help` really puzzled me...